# boost::optional - using boost::in_place for the object which constuctor takes other object by the reference

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-optional

I try to use boost::in_place for the non-movable and non-copyable object which constructor takes other object by the reference:

```
struct A
{
};

struct B
{
    B(A& a): a_(a){}

    B(B const &) = delete;
    B(B&&) = delete;
    B& operator=(B const &) = delete;
    B& operator=(B&) = delete;

    A& a_;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    boost::optional<B> op(boost::in_place(a));

    return 0;
}
```

The code doesn't compile: binding reference of type ‘A&’ to ‘const A’ discards qualifiers

How to fix that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the inplace constructor.

In boost, this is [this constructor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/detailed_semantics___optional_values.html#reference_optional_in_place_init), that takes a `in_place_init_t` variable, then constructs in place with the following arguments.

```
boost::optional<B> op(boost::in_place_init, a);
// Calls `B::B(A&) with `a`
```

Or to continue using `in_place`, which by default takes a const reference, specify that it isn't a const reference:

```
boost::optional<B> op(boost::in_place<A&>(a));
```

Comment: I have to use boost 1.58 and I can't see in_place_init there so I have to use a second solution which you have posted.

Comment: @Irbis It was probably added to be more inline with how `std::optional` works. The documentation for `boost::in_place` is quite shoddy, but I managed to make it work with the `in_place` factory (Docs [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/in_place_factories.html))